# What is this component (labelled L1)?

Tags: inductor, identification

What is this component? It looks a bit like a capacitor, but not exactly, and it is labelled L1 on a small circuit board where there are capacitors labelled C2 and C3…

[image: Mystery Component]

Comment: As Majenko says, it's a wire wound inductor on a ferrite core (99.99% probability). If you tell us what the circuit is for and/or show us a photo of the wider context we can prbably add more information.

Comment: Any other markings, e.g. digits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An inductor.

Essentially a coil of wire round a ferrite core.

Here's one without the heatshrink around it:

[image]

Comment: What is the marking to the right of the "CB" and does the "CB" mean anything? (the manufacturer perhaps?)

Comment: It's most likely the markings of the manufacturer of the heat-shrink sleeving the inductor is encased in.

Comment: Thanks! Now to go dust off an electronics textbook and try to understand what an inductor does… :-)